# How do I replace "Activities" with an application menu in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: panel, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool, activities-overview

Installed tweak tool but I cant find the extension to get rid of activities replace it with the old style application list.

Is their an article here that would direct me? I really do not like the new gnome windows 10 style.

Answer (score 2):

Install and activate GNOME shell extension *Applications Menu* from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/). Visit this webpage via Firefox or Google Chrome, you'll be prompted to install a browser add-on/extension first. Install the add-on/extension and then you'll able to install Applications Menu just by clicking a button.

If you want to disable "*Activities*" button try [Hide Activities Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/744/hide-activities-button/) extension.

If you want to disable hot-corner feature to show Activities overview try [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) extension.

Once installed you'll be able to manage extensions from the "Extensions" section of GNOME Tweak Tool.

Comment: @GaetanoGiacalone If you find this answer useful you [may "accept" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it.

Comment: not useful.. 'Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.'

Comment: @razor What is "*not useful*"? If you just bothered to check the documentation it's referring to, you would have found out that one needs to install `chrome-gnome-shell` package (along with the browser extension) to be able to install and manage GNOME extensions from the browser. But then again I guess it's easier to comment "*not useful*" :-)

Comment: yes, i bothered, i've installed 'chrome-gnome-shell' before, Chromium and Firefox display this error.....

Comment: it looks like 'chrome-gnome-shell' needed python2, but not mentioned it in dependencies...
ubuntu:GNOME

Comment: @razor Ah! So that means you have made changes to your system which made that package ineffective? Then you'll have to fix that first. Or you can [manually install](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029180/480481) extensions and manage them using GNOME Tweaks.

Comment: did i ?  i didn't remove python2, there was just python3 after fresh install